# Is Java javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse sendRedirect() auto replace the carriage return(%0d%0a) to prevent Http Header Splitting attack?

Tags: http, java, injection

I just tried to demonstrate a simple Web app program to simulate the Http Header Splitting attack but I failed. I realise that this sendRedirect() function has filtered my carriage return and replace to space (%20). I wanna to confirm whether I am right or I doing the wrong way. Any comment and and suggestion are welcome.

**For your information**

- Server info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
- Servlet version: 3.0
- JSP version: 2.1
- Java version: 1.7.0_51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GlassFish does filter newline characters in headers. Tomcat does as well. I don't know about other servlet containers (Jetty, WebSphere, etc.)

com.sun.net.httpserver does NOT filter newlines, so you can use that for your simulation.

Comment: I new to JSP. Do you mind to provide the sample code that I should replace sendRedirect() to simulate the CLRF attack? I can't find the method redirect in com.sun.net.httpserver or I miss understand something? Thank you.

Comment: Did you get a basic web server working? Roughly speaking, you need to do httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Location", "Blah\nBlah")

Comment: Yup, my Web server is working. Do I need to change the server? Cause I am still using the GlassFish. I roughly got what you mean from the code. I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: @overshadow - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/LightweightHTTPServer.htm

Comment: I see, you mean create a server to handle the http request. Haha. Thank you very much. Your help is very much appreciated.